# C#: For-loop explanation

Tags: c#, oop, for-loop

I have an question regarding for loops in C#.

My code:

```
 for(i = 1; i < 100; i*=2) 
 {
    Console.Write(i + " ");
 }
 Console.Readkey();
```

I think that the result should be  "2 4 8 16 32 64" but I get "1 2 4 8 16 32 64".
Where did "1" come from?

Comment: [C# for reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx)

Comment: The loop is working but I don't understand the output.

Comment: My answer explains why you're seeing that output

Comment: I think you do not understand the meaning of *= then. This operator is the short from i = i*2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are initializing i as 1 with i=1, which is where the 1 comes from.

The increment (your i*=; portion) doesn't get called until the loop has completed at least once, so it doesn't get to the next value until after it displays the value of i, which is 1

To see what you're expecting, you need to change the loop to:

```
for(i = 2; i < 100; i*=2) 
 {
    Console.Write(i + " ");
 }
 Console.Readkey();
```

Comment: Thanks, now I get it.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please accept it as an answer if it's helpful

Answer (score 4):

I know you already get your correct answer but I want to explain more deep because I assume you are a beginner programmer.

From [`$8.8.3` The for statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664753%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in C# spec;

```
for-statement:
    for (   for-initializer   ;   for-condition   ;   for-iterator   )   embedded-statement
```

> A for statement is executed as follows:
>
> - If a for-initializer is present, the variable initializers or statement expressions are executed in the order they are written. This
>     step is only performed once.
> - If a for-condition is present, it is evaluated.
> - If the for-condition is not present or if the evaluation yields true, control is transferred to the embedded statement. **When and if
>     control reaches the end point of the embedded statement (possibly from
>     execution of a continue statement), the expressions of the
>     for-iterator, if any, are evaluated in sequence**, and then another
>     iteration is performed, starting with evaluation of the for-condition
>     in the step above.
> - If the for-condition is present and the evaluation yields false, control is transferred to the end point of the for statement.

As you can see, *for-iterator* (which is `i*=2` in your case) will not executed *until* you complete the first iteration since since `i < 100` returns `true` for `i = 1`.

Since [a picture is worth a thousand words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_picture_is_worth_a_thousand_words), so..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are starting with i=1 therefore your first number is 1.

The for loop is made of three elements : start , condition and step.

I will try to explain few steps so you can get the idea.

First you go in with 1, you print it. Then it gets to i*=2 which is the equivalent of i=i*2.After this the condition is verified, if it is true then proceed to the execution block again. Hope this cleared it up for you. Also you are just multiplying by 2, not raising at the power of 2, which is explained in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use

```
for(i = 2; i <= 100; i=i*2) 
 {
    Console.Write(i + " ");
 }
 Console.Readkey();
```